# Response from server coming as null in the client(IOS) on async call in app development

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am making an asynchronous call to the server from the client, and printing data on the server.
But the response which i get at the client is coming as null

My response retrieval part is as under:-

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [receivedData setLength:0];
    NSLog(@"connection did receive response");

}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    // Append the new data to receivedData.
    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere
    if(!receivedData)
    {
        receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
    }

    [receivedData appendData:data];

    NSLog(@"connection did receive data");
}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
  didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // inform the user
    NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",

    [error localizedDescription],
    [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
}


- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // receivedData is declared as a method instance elsewhere
    NSString *responseFromServer = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
    NSLog(@"connection did finish load");
    NSLog(@"response from the server=%@", responseFromServer);
 }
```

So 'responseFromServer' value is coming as null.

Can anybody tell me where am i going wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not strongly referencing receivedData, you may want to start doing it

`receivedData = [NSMutableData data];` is an autoreleased object. Make sure that receivedData is a strong or retained property, then set it like so `self.receivedData = [NSMutableData data];`

It's a possibility that receivedData is getting autoreleased before the final connectionDelegate method fires, thus the responseString is using nil data in the initWithData method

Comment: It's okay if `receivedData` is declared as `strong` and he does use ARC. Simple assignment in this case _retains_ it = makes strong reference. If he doesn't use `strong` & `ARC`, it's wrong.

Comment: well if he's not using ARC, the line `self.receivedData = [NSMutableData data];` != `receivedData = [NSMutableData data];`. It's the difference between encapsulating the call with `retain` like `receivedData = [[NSMutableData data]retain];`

Comment: I am using ARC as i mentioned in comments ie. ARC is enabled in build settings.Well i am declaring receivedData as NSMutableData *receivedData; which makes it strong (due to *). Hope i am on the same page. Is there any other way to declare strong vars.

Comment: well i changed receivedData to a property like this: @property (strong) NSMutableData *receivedData; and used self.receivedData everywhere and it worked. at - Justin u got it right man.. Thanks a lot.

Comment: good. since you're using `[NSMutableData data];` you are getting an autoreleased object. You could use `[[NSMutableData alloc] init];` to get a non-autoreleased object, and you wouldn't have to use `self.receivedData = `. Using `self.` just forces the usage of the proper getter/setter, and if you've @synthesized your properties these are written for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `receivedData` contains UTF8 encoded data = string? `initWithData:encoding:` documentation ...

**Return Value**

An NSString object initialized by converting the bytes in data into Unicode characters using encoding. The returned object may be different from the original receiver. **Returns nil if the initialization fails for some reason (for example if data does not represent valid data for encoding).**

... as you can see, it returns nil if initialization fails.

Comment: I am using phone-gap 2.1.0.Does it have any impact on this. In phonegap 1.3 , this thing was working. I have declared receivedData as : NSMutableData *receivedData; in .h file

Comment: Dunno, but if you check that `receivedData` does really contain some data in `connectionDidFinishLoading:`, it means that `NSString *` can't be initialized from these data - thus your `responseFromServer` is `nil`. Put breakpoint in `connectionDidFinishLoading:` and check your `receivedData` first.

Comment: I am printing receiveData as NSLog(@"rec data=%@", receivedData); But it is also coming blank and App is terminating. Am i printing it correctly.

Comment: My response header info is as under:-Connection = close;
    "Content-Length" = 190;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Mon, 01 Oct 2012 14:16:13 GMT";
    Server = "Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)";
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.3.3";

Comment: See my comment on another answer - do you use `strong` for `receivedData` and do you use ARC?

Comment: Yes i am using strong for receivedData. Its declared as : NSMutableData *receivedData; in .h file. And I am using ARC.. Which answer are you talking abt..?